# How to output key,value pairs of different types from a map/reduce function?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a class myOutput which contains data members like -

```
class myOutput{
int id;
double value;
double variance;
}
```

I want to output two values to two different files

File 1: Object of myOutput
File 2: A TextWritable value

I read up on MultipleOutputFormat but I think it does not allows to write values of different types. How can I achieve this from a map function? What should be my job configuration settings?

Comment: Do you want to write the variables in **myOutput** (should be **MyOutput**) to a file?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's being asked here. I've provided a generalized solution that should be suitable for this sort of thing.

Comment: @ Sam ... No I need to write values generated in my map function to HDFS. There are two objects generated, one is of type MyOutput which is a class I have written and the other is a String. (apologies for the poor naming)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FileOutputStream` and [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) together to serialize your `myOutput` instance. This will store all fields, so that the instance can be reloaded/deserialized at some point.

If that's the route you decide to take, you will need to implement [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

I'm not sure what `TextWritable` is. If you're just trying to write a `String` to a file then use a [Printwriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html). If it's another class instance that you've created, then you can use the same technique mentioned above.